# ¿Cómo convertir varchar a hora?

Tags: sql-server

en nuestra tabla recibo la hora de la siguiente manera `'184030'`, la idea es convertir eso a `18:40:30`
He intentado utilizar `(try_convert(time,hora,103))` pero no funciono. ¿cual seria la manera?

Answer (score 2):

Ocurre que el formato no es el adecuado para que sea interpretado como un `Time`, puedes confirmarlo haciendo:

```
select try_convert(time,'18:40:30')

18:40:30
```

Para convertir adecuadamente, simplemente hay que agregar los `:` a la cadena, por ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @Hora   VARCHAR(8)
SET @Hora = '184030'

SELECT try_convert(time, SUBSTRING(@Hora, 1, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@Hora, 3, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@Hora, 5, 2))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio. Ya que el hormato no es el adecuado, no declare ninguna variable y utilice el substring para agregarle el formato. 
Asi: left(try_convert(time, SUBSTRING(columna, 1, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(columna, 3, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(columna, 5, 2)),5). Le agrego el left para que me traiga solo hora y minutos. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma de hacerlo sería con [`STUFF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

> The `STUFF` function inserts a string into another string. It deletes
> a specified length of characters in the first string at the start
> position and then inserts the second string into the first string at
> the start position.
>
> ---
>
> La función `STUFF` inserta una cadena dentro de otra cadena. Elimina
> una longitud específica de caracteres en la primera cadena en la
> posición de inicio y luego inserta la segunda cadena en la primera
> cadena en la posición de inicio.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(STUFF(STUFF('184030',5,0,':'),3,0,':') AS TIME)
```

Lo que ocurre aquí es que:

- `STUFF('184030',5,0,':')` agregará `:` en la posición `5` de la cadena, es decir: `1840:30`
- Y el otro `STUFF` agregará `:` en la posición `3` de la cadena, es decir: `18:40:30`

**Salida:**

```
18:40:30
```

### Solución óptima: Normalizar

Aunque la solución más óptima sería **normalizar tus datos** si es posible, haciendo que la columna que recibe la información sea del tipo más adecuado, evitando así conversiones o manipulaciones que ralentizan el código. O, evitando datos erróneos en la inserción.

Para este caso, **normalizar** sería relativamente simple, aunque la BD esté en producción. Sería algo como:

- crear una columna del tipo `time` (o `datetime` si tuvieras la fecha por otro lado, desperdiciando espacio)
- luego ejecutar un código en el que se convierta cada valor de la columna vieja y se actualice la nueva columna
- verificar que todo está OK, es decir, que no hay nulos en la columna nueva, porque si los hay, deberás verificar ese valor erróneo en la columna vieja. Con suerte sabrás de dónde vino ese dato erróneo, pero ¿y si no lo sabes, cómo vas a saber cuál era el dato correcto cuando se insertó / modificó? Ese es uno de los grandes problemas de crear columnas con tipos de datos que dan como buenos datos que son erróneos (me refiero a que haya horas del tipo `9999999999` o parecido.
- Pues esperando que no te encuentres con datos erróneos, una vez verificado eso, tendrías que verificar el código, puede que haya otras partes donde hagas conversiones, etc. Debes identificar ese código para corregirlo.
- Finalmente, corriges el código, borras la columna vieja y renombras la columna nueva con el nombre de la vieja.

Es un ejemplo de proceso de normalización. En bases de datos con alta concurrencia no es tan simple (hablamos de que un error, o un segundo de código disfuncional te puede crear un gravísimo problema y ya tendrías que pensar en normalizar de otro modo). Lo que quiero que entiendes es que diseñar mal puede tener gravísimas consecuencias, sobre todo cuando estás en producción...

Sea como sea, antes de intentar cualquier cambio, haz un backup, si tu base de datos está en producción.

Answer (score 0):

Existen múltiples formas. Otra alternativa es usar la función `STUFF`. (que acabo de ver que ya publicaron mientras terminaba mi respuesta)

```
DECLARE @Hora VARCHAR(8) = '184030';

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(TIME, STUFF( STUFF(@Hora, 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':'));
```

Y Microsoft usa algo similar a esto para convertir sus fechas y horas en la base de datos msdb.

```
DECLARE @Hora  varchar(8) = '184030';

SELECT CAST( CONCAT( @Hora / 10000, ':', 
                    (@Hora % 10000)/100, ':', 
                     @Hora % 100) AS time);
```